# Functional component with v-once effect

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm writing a lightweight [functional component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) with `render` function (specifically a horizontal `<Divider/>` component) where I need it to render only once, for optimized update performance; and it doesn't need to be reactive at all since it should only serve as static content once rendered. It will, however, take some basic props (e.g. `color`, `height`, etc.) for the divider since it's actually built on top of SVG.

Now, with templates in [single-file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), you get to use [`v-once`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) on the containing element as well as mark it as `functional`, and it basically lets you set the props on initial rendering—from which point on—it will go static and renderless (which is great for this purpose), something like so:

```vue
<template functional>
  <div class="divider" v-once>
    <svg>
      <g>
        <path :fill="color" d="Mxx.xxx..."></path>
        <!-- And more paths for complex dividers -->
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

While that works as expected, there seems to be no way to set the same `VNode.isOnce` flag on the component with `render` function—further [confirmed by Evan](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5455#issuecomment-294347354) that `v-once` is a compile-level directive and thus not available inside `render` functions—which is too bad given how you could get the same effect with template-based components.

#### The `functional` component with `render` function:

```js
export default {
  functional: true,

  render(h, context) {
    // As a non-static component, this function will always get called
    // on each update! How can I apply some static flag at this point?   
    
    const data = {
      style: {
        textAlign: 'center'
      }    
    };

    const svgs = [
      h('svg', ...)    
    ];

    return h(context.props.tag, data, svgs);
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any take or experience on this?

Answer (score 2):

`v-once` is not a "real" directive. The Vue template compiler will generate code which caches the vnodes of templates marked with `v-once`.

Since you're writing the render function by hand, you will have to take care of caching the vnodes generated by your render function.

You can try something like this (untested and likely has issues):

```es6
const cache = new WeakMap()

export default {
  functional: true,

  render(h, ctx) {
    // Get cache map from parent component instance
    if (!cache.has(ctx.parent)) {
      cache.set(ctx.parent, new Map())
    }

    const vnodeCache = cache.get(ctx.parent)

    // Determine the cache key from the props (we only use one prop here)
    const cacheKey = ctx.props.fill

    // Get the cached vnode
    let vnode = vnodeCache.get(cacheKey)

    if (!vnode) {
      // Render
      vnode = h('div', `Fill is ${ctx.props.fill}`)

      // This is necessary so Vue will reuse the previous DOM elements during patch
      vnode.isStatic = true
      vnode.isOnce = true

      // Store in cache
      vnodeCache.set(cacheKey, vnode)
    }

    return vnode
  }
}
```

I can't guarantee that the above code will work properly in all situations since it is quite low level, and I don't know if vnodes can/should be cached in this way. The caching code can be more or less complex than the above depending on your requirements.

Interestingly, using `v-once` in a functional component won't prevent the render code of that template subtree from being executed in full (which is what you want to avoid from your question), although since the vnode has `isStatic` and `isOnce` marked as true, Vue will reuse the previous rendering when patching the DOM.

All in all, this is quite overkill, and I recommend you needn't bother with `v-once` and caching unless you have determined it to be a performance issue after profiling.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's not quite a performance issue with this low-level component by far (since you won't probably have that many divider on a page); I just thought that it would be a nice pattern for building one-off, renderless components with functional rendering considering the fact that it is a closer-to-the-compiler alternative to templates. Think about the possibility to build other types of component that you do want treated as mere static contents.

Comment: I might resort to this separate vnodes template caching, although I think there really should be a way to circumvent the lack of ability to attaching "internal" directives on a functional component.